# Dart Angular form pristine/dirty dynamics

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have a user list and user detail component, similar to the setup in the tutorial with hero list/detail, where selecting the user in the list should make it editable in the detail component. The problem is that changing the user makes the form dirty. To make it clearer here is the stripped down code:

```
@Component(...)
class UserDetail {
  @Input()
  User user;
  Future onSubmit() async {...}
}
```

And the template is as follows:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #userEditForm="ngForm">
    <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
    <input type="checkbox"
        id="is_happy"
        [(ngModel)]="user.is_happy"
        ngControl="is_happy"
        #is_happy="ngForm" />
    <div [hidden]="userEditForm.pristine">
        <material-button
            [disabled]="!userEditForm.valid"
            (trigger)="onSubmit()">
            Update
        </material-button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to make it so that the form is only dirty if the user interacts with the controls, not when the underlying user changes from the outside.

What is the *right* way to do this? Is there a way to reset the form on user change? I haven't found anything I can easily use to achieve this simple use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question.

This is an unfortunate side effect of the default value accessor. It is creating a feedback loop that causes the control to become dirty on a write. Notice on this [line](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/2afa8bb8e704fcc147c69576ea306b11834eaccb/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/default_value_accessor.dart#L43) when a value is being written to the input it causes an 'input' event on the input. This is then caught [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/2afa8bb8e704fcc147c69576ea306b11834eaccb/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/default_value_accessor.dart#L25). Which then causes the change function to be called on the control which causes it be dirty :(

So what options do you have:

- Don't use dirty but use touched instead. This is only set on blur so it would mostly be caused by a user action.
- Use angular_component's material-input which listens to the [keypress](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/e0f5073ae5e73c9d6cb6e481f89424087d2c780f/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input_default_value_accessor.dart#L24) or [onblur](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/e0f5073ae5e73c9d6cb6e481f89424087d2c780f/lib/src/components/material_input/material_input_default_value_accessor.dart#L41) events for changes instead of an input event.
- Write your own ControlValueAccessor that is a hybrid between the DefaultValueAccessor and material-input linked above. By hybrid I mean it uses keypress or blur instead of 'input' as the onChange event.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Since material-input is a text field, I tried using material-checkbox, but that behaves the same as a regular checkbox. I think there is no custom value accessor code [there](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/e0f5073ae5e73c9d6cb6e481f89424087d2c780f/lib/src/components/material_checkbox).
Also, do you know if there is any documentation on writing ValueAccessors? I tried that on my own previously, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: There is actually custom value accessor code, but it has the same problem as the default accessor. Here is where it is [set](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/e0f5073ae5e73c9d6cb6e481f89424087d2c780f/lib/src/components/material_checkbox/material_checkbox.dart#L113) and here is where it is marked [dirty](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/e0f5073ae5e73c9d6cb6e481f89424087d2c780f/lib/src/components/material_checkbox/material_checkbox.dart#L118) since it is using the standard check input it is also calling the dirty bit.

Comment: There isn't any separate documentation on it. Following one of the ValueAccessors I linked above is the best we have at the moment. We'll get it on the list to write some better documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think I'll try the custom value accessor option.

Comment: And just a note, I tried using touched, but that didn't work at all. The form remained untouched even when I interacted with the material-checkbox.

Comment: Looks like material_checkbox doesn't have the touched behavior. Just material_input. I'll create a bug to fix that.